# Night's watch torsos

Tags: minifigure-identification, castle

Are the torsos in [this eBay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/The-Nights-Watch-Game-of-Thrones-Lego-Moc-Minifigure-Collection-/303178532026) made by LEGO? If so, can anyone identify them?

Comment: Bricklink doesn't even know what is "game of thrones" so I think these are from a third-party company. In fact I see that game of thrones sets are actually made by Mega Construct and Lego wouldn't buy this license anyway. Should I post this as answer?

Comment: The capes look a little fuzzy, those minifigure heads don't seem to exist, and I'm failing to recognize the hair anyways, which increases the chances of it being from clone-brand.

Answer (score 7):

From the EBay listing you posted:

> Precise Molded & Printed Items (MOC-My Own Creations)

Ergo, these are custom minifigs, not made by LEGO.

Comment: Indeed. Anyone could've found out whether they were real or not with a few google/BL searches.